# jqGrid stuck on loading?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am trying to use the JQuery plugin [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) with an asp .net mvc app.

I am passing the grid a JSON object in the following [format](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0f6jhe.htm) as in the jqGrid documentation:

```
{
    "total":1,
    "page":1,
    "records":10,
    "rows":
        [{
        "i":1,"cell":["foo","bar"]},
           {"i":2,"cell":["foo1","barr"]},
           {"i":3,"cell":["foo2","barrr"]}]
}
```

and the jqGrid is setup:

```
jQuery("#searchResults").jqGrid({
                    url: '/Customer/SearchResults/',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    colNames: ['Surname', 'Forename'],
                    colModel: [
                      { name: 'Surname', index: 'Surname', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                      { name: 'Forename', index: 'Forename', width: 200, align: 'left'}],
                    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                    sortname: 'Id',
                    sortorder: "desc",
                    viewrecords: true,
                    imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
                    caption: 'My first grid'
                });
```

Its hitting my action but the grid is stuck on loading, any ideas what I am doing wrong??

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the grid is "stuck on loading" that generally means that the grid has either not received a response or that the response contains data it could not used to populate the grid. The first thing to look at is the response itself, in either Firebug's Net tab or Fiddler. Make sure it is actually JSON and not a 500 error or an HTML error message. Second, they very careful attention to JavaScript errors. You will need to use Firebug or IE 8's debugger (which you must manually turn on) in order to catch the errors, because otherwise they may be well hidden; JavaScript errors do not tend to be obvious to the user. You can then trace through the call stack to figure out why the grid does not like your data.

That said, doing this manually is a bit of a pain, which is why [I wrote extension methods to create appropriately-formatted data for the grid from any IQueryable](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/17/38229/).

Comment: thanks, got it working, it was an error in my html! i actually stumbled across your blog while trying to figure this out, very helpful!
still got a problem with the loading overlay, it wouldnt remove its self once the data was loaded, i just edited the jqGrid file.

Comment: Thanks!  random javascript error for me was causing this.  Fixed that and poof! it was working.

Comment: Usually this is due to when you FORGET to add translation file in i8n folder. At least one is required to be in there. People tend to put js and css and try it.

Answer (score 0):

After following Craig Stuntz' advice, I saw with Firebug that I was getting a 500 error.  For me, it ended up being a bad DB connection string.  I was using a MVC 3 solution posted on Codeplex as a template.  The solution consisted of multiple projects and two of the projects had connection strings.  I overlooked one of them.  I kept tinkering with IIS application pool settings, and DB permissions, until I found the other connection string.

Hope this is helpful to someone.

Answer (score -1):

sometimes it happenes and loop stucks in js file ,
i think you should try this

repeateditems : false
my problem is solved....